# Script variables in C-shell

Tags: shell, unix, grep, csh

There is a my_grep script

```
#!/bin/csh
cat $1 | grep -i -E " a | b "
```

How come

```
cat a* | grep -i -E " a | b " > out1.txt
```

and

```
my_grep a* > out2.txt
```

yield different results?

Comment: Don't use c-shell for scripting. Google "C shell why not".

Comment: That's correct, but the problem is independent of the shell; with bash one gets exactly the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a*` will expand in shell before going to shell script.  Thus, `my_grep a*` will give only the first file starting with `a` to be processed by your script.  On the other hand, `cat a*` will work on all the files starting with `a*`.  You can change the script to `cat $*` and that will achieve the desired result.

Comment: `$*` is almost never the optimal solution for this problem. Use `"$@"` in sh-like shells (bash, ksh, dash, sh), and `$*:q` in csh-like shells (tcsh, csh) instead.

Answer (score 1):

That would be because `$1` is the *first* argument rather than all of them.

The shell will expand the wildcard into individual files before your script sees it.

So, if you have the following two files `a1` and `a2`, the command `my_grep a*` will give you the two files into `$1` and `$2` and your script will only process the first.

Answer (score 1):

### Quick solution:

They differ because you are only cating the FIRST glob expansion `$1` in my_grep script ... 
Your my_grep should be:

```
#!/bin/csh

cat $* | grep -i -E " a | b "
```

the $* are all the command-line arguments passed to my_grep.

### Some detail

The command-line shell (where you are actually typing `my_grep a*` is expanding the a* to all the filenames that begin with `a` so let's say you had `afoo` `abar` and `abaz` in you directory, then:

`cat a* | grep -i -E " a | b "`

is essentially equivalent to:

`cat abar abaz afoo | grep -i -E " a | b "`

similarly when you do my_grep a*

it's equivalent to

`my_grep abar abaz afoo`

so in you shell script `cat $1`  means JUST `cat abar` and NOT `cat abar abaz afoo`

`$*` is equivalent of `$argv` (which is equivalent of `$argv[*]`).

so your my_grep should be as shown above.